# Combine AND and OR in a ElementQuery

Tags: elementquery, yii

I have a category with 2 levels. And I want to be able to let the user do a search based on those. The problem is that it needs to be `AND` between all level 1 categories, and `OR` within child categories. So let's say I have a category structure like this:

```
- Elevator
- Air condition
- View
  - Ocean
  - Mountains
  - Garden
```

Now when a user selects `elevator`, `ocean` and `mountains` I want to return all entries that have `elevator AND (ocean OR mountains)`

I tried this: `$entries->categories(['and', 695, ['or', 698, 697]]);`, but that doesn't work, as it seems to just skip the `['or', 698, 697]` part.

**Edit for bounty:** In addition to the reason given above, there is also a change in the requirement since we added multiple categories. So for one category group, the operator needs to be `OR`, and some groups should have `AND`.

Comment: I take it you want to do this in a plugin, not twig?

Comment: Yeah. But I guess it would be very similar solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand properly, you should be able to do this:

```php
$entries = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
    ->section('yourSection')
    ->category(['and', 695])
    ->relatedTo([698,698])->all();
```

Assuming `category` is the name of your relational field, you can use that to pass the `and` condition (though with one element only it wouldn't be needed) then `relatedTo` is an `or` by default ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#simple-relationships))

And as per your edit, pass `and` condition to your custom fied and `or` conditions to your `relatedTo`.

It would be pretty much the same in Twig.

Comment: Yes! So simple, so effective! And this would work perfectly with my other scenario where there's different operators for different category groups as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to comment, so trying an answer.
Did you tried to build a custom hierarchy by scrolling the content of each level in a custom object ?

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean. Could you explain a bit more? What kind of custom object and custom hierarchy?